# installing reactnative for android on macOS Catlina

Tags: macos, react-native

i try to install reactnative today
been following tutorial from here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

when i try to run the test project
it failed to load emulator

chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra AwesomeProject % npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

can anyone help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must create at least one AVD (Android Virtual Device) in order to run it in the emulator. It seems that you don't have any. An easy way to check is to run the following command:

```sh
emulator -list-avds

# Example output
Nougat_7
Pixel_2_API_29_Google_Play_
```

If the output of the command is empty, it means you don't have any AVDs yet. In this case you can create an AVD by opening Android Studio and then clicking the *Configure* menu and after that opening *AVD Manager*. In *AVD Manager* you can create a new virtual device which you can later run in the emulator.

Comment: i have 2 already
chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra ~ % emulator -list-avds
Android
Pixel_3a_API_30_x86

Comment: There is another error: /bin/sh: adb: command not found  - can you try running `$ adb version` in the terminal and see if there is an output?

Comment: chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra ~ % adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.0-6374843
Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb

Comment: but the adb devices is empty
chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra ~ % adb devices           
List of devices attached

Comment: Can you try starting the emulator manually (e.g. from Android Studio or running `emulator @Android Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 `)? Then run the react-native command to see if it succeeds this time.

Comment: there is a popup saying unable to locate adb, but the emulator works well

Comment: well, after i open the emulator manualy from android studio, there is emulator when i check 'chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra ~ % adb devices        
List of devices attached
emulator-5554 device'

Comment: when i try to run it
`chandra@MacBook-Pro-Chandra AwesomeProject % npx react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 967 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings`

Comment: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/Users/chandra/Desktop/AwesomeProject/android/local.properties'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

`

Comment: `error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/chandra/Desktop/AwesomeProject
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c react-native "run-android"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/chandra/.npm/_logs/2021-01-17T11_00_19_768Z-debug.log``